# Function semantic-analyze-proto-impl-togle doesn't work

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'm using emacs23.2 with cedet-1.0.1. And here is a project directory:

./include/a.h

./src/a.cpp

I've already add ../include into the semantic-dependancy-system-include-path and verified it by describe-variable.

Everything looks fine including semantic-ia-fast-jump which can jump between a.cpp and a.h.
However, semantic-analyze-proto-impl-togle doesn't work at all: Cannot find suitable prototype (I opened ./src/a.cpp and put point at A::f(), it couldn't jump to ./include/a.h. But the weird thing is my minibuffer displayed: a.h: void f();).

And when I put a.h and a.cpp into the same directory: ./, it works. So I guess there is something wrong with the include-path, but ../include is actually in the include-path.

Anyone can help me here?